# How to Implement Audit Trail In Spring MVC with SQL?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We have developed a Spring **MVC** application for **UAT**.
Now our client is asking for Audit Trail.
Requirement Should be A proper Trail(***SQL Entry or File***) with one user which he was Audited.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to audit each Database transactions. You can use

```
@PrePersist
public void onPrePersist() { ... }

@PreUpdate
public void onPreUpdate() { ... }

@PreRemove
public void onPreRemove() { ... }
```

Before this entity is persisted. onPrePersist() will be called and you can add that entry 
to another table say AUDIT_LOG

There are many examples available

[database-auditing-jpa](http://%20http://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa)

[auditing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.DATAJPA-580-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/auditing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Hibernate Envers (http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/). With this dependency, you can enable the auditing of all your database entities. If you are using `Spring Security` you can also audit which user made the change. Josh Long (@starbuxman) published a nice video about Hibernate Envers (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2E8_0Qxi6Tg)